# Sending char* to char *[]

Tags: c

Sorry for the long codes. I'm developing a command program that tokenizing the user commands. If I enter "Hello world "hi guys" ",

```
temp[0] = "Hello"
temp[1] = "world"
temp[2] = "hi guys"
```

Now I'm struggling with the store_token function. I have to print tokens like this.

```
tokens[0] = "Hello"
tokens[1] = "world"
tokens[2] = "hi guys"
```

temp is a temporary bridge that stores cut tokens. So I write like this

```
(*tokens)[i] = (*temp)[i]
```

because 'tokens' is char *[], and I want to access the element of 'tokens'
to store the char * of the temp.

Here is some problem. I can't figure out the (*tokens)[i] and I don't know
what it directs.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, the smallest amount of complete code that anyone can run exactly as shown to reproduce the problem.

Comment: How is the function called? What is passed in, in which manner, and how is it defined an initialised? As it stands the question is incomplete and with this not answerable. At least not without guessing, what I wouldn't do. BTW, if there were pictures linked I do not see them.

Comment: When programming, remember that screens are often shorter than they are wide.  Don't arrange your code for maximum height, it makes it hard to read the code because very little of it fits on the screen.

Comment: `*"\""`!? It's just `'"'`

Comment: okay iI will make this code looks easier

Comment: You have updated the code, but the problem is still unclear.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem in code readability.  You have some code that almost works; but, because you have not invested in readaility, you can't find your error.

I would start by clarifying the "reset / complete the token operation" and "add to token" operations.  If any code flow doesn't do one or the other, there's a bug.

```
for (int i = 0; i < clen; i++) {
    if (*command == *"\"" ) {
        isnested = !isnested;
        continue;
    } else if (*command == *"\n") {
        toklen = 0;
        ntoken++;
    } else if (isspace(*command) && !(isnested)) {
        if (doublespace) {
            *command++;
            continue;
        } else {
            doublespace = true;
            ntoken++;
            toklen = 0;
        }
    } else {
        doublespace = false;
        temp[ntoken][toklen] = *command;
        toklen++;
    }
    *command++;
}
*nr_tokens = ntoken;
```

Assuming that adding to `toklen` indicates "add to the token" and `toklen = 0` signals a "complete the token" I would rewrite the code

```
for (int i = 0; i < clen; i++) {
    if (*command == *"\"" ) {
        isnested = !isnested;
        continue;
    } else if (*command == *"\n") {
        completeToken();
    } else if (isspace(*command) && !(isnested)) {
        if (doublespace) {
            *command++;
            continue;
        } else {
            doublespace = true;
            completeToken();
        }
    } else {
        doublespace = false;
        addToken(*command);
    }
    *command++;
}
*nr_tokens = ntoken;
```

And now a few things are clear.

0. There are code flows through your algorithm that don't add to the token and don't complete the token.  These code flows need simplified and put up front (so everyone can see what isn't important).
1. You don't add the quotes to a `isnested` token.  Maybe your lexer strips the quotes; but, if it does, there's no token completion when we are exit the quotes.
2. Your lexer handles new lines without regard to the `isnested` variable.  Odds are it should be adding the newline to the string if inside a set of quotes.
3. Your lexer is very concerned with double spaces.  Normally, if spaces are being stripped, they are stripped without regard to how many exist.

Even in small blocks of code, readability matters.  C's history ignores modern readability rules, as the rules came out after the language; but, you would do well to apply them anyway, so you can get the modern readability benefits within the C operating enviornment.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I will fix the problem